# Create object dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating a system where data is coming from a database. This data represents certain object that has to be created dynamically.

Now to let the object work into a build framework that I use. I need to set the object at the top of my class like this.

```
public class PageGeneratorWidget
{
    public ColorPickerWidget com1 { get; protected set; } 

    public PageGeneratorWidget(string dataId){
     //SOME CODE LIKE
     //com1.Type = "flat";
    }
}
```

To set the properties of the object dynamically isn't a problem. The problem that I experience is that I don't know how I can dynamically create the

```
public ColorPickerWidget com1 {get; protected set;}
```

Does anyone know some solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to create a class dynamically or create an instance dynamically?

Comment: Is the `type` of com1 known at compile time?

Comment: I am not seeing how any of this is dynamic or a problem. Either the constructor of PageGeneratorWidget initializes com1, or change the constructor to take in a ColorPickerWidget and set it to com1. Either way PageGeneratorWidget should never exist with com1 uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

You solution is hidden in Generics.

Your code should should look like this.

```
public class PageGeneratorWidget<T>
{
    public T com1 { get; protected set; } 

    public PageGeneratorWidget(string dataId){
     //SOME CODE LIKE
     //com1.Type = "flat";
    }
}
```

And use it by declaring the objects of the class like this

```
PageGeneratorWidget<ColorPickerWidget> my object =
     new PageGeneratorWidget<ColorPickerWidget>();
```

Keep reading [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice, that will work. Also I had a look and it is possible to send more objects by once, but is there a way to set certain objects without the pageGeneratorWidget knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe create the object in the constructor of PageGeneratorWidget:

```
public class PageGeneratorWidget
{
    public ColorPickerWidget com1 { get; protected set; } 

    public PageGeneratorWidget(string dataId){
     //SOME CODE LIKE
     //com1.Type = "flat";
    com1 = new ColorPickerWidget(); // Use color Picker Widget constructor
    }
}
```

You could also have `PageGeneratorWidget` constructor take a parameter of type `ColorPickerWidget` and set com1 to that value.